# Calling a generic extension method without specifying as many types

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

Here is a snippet of a class I use for testing Type extension methods:

```
class Something
{
  [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Must have between 1 and 100 characters")]
  public string SomePublicString { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
  public static TAttributeType GetCustomAttribute<T, TAttributeType, TProperty>(this T value, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyLambda, bool inherit = false)
  {
    var type = typeof(T);
    var member = (MemberExpression)propertyLambda.Body;
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
    var customAttributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttributeType), inherit);

    return customAttributes.OfType<TAttributeType>().FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

**Usage in a unit test:**

```
1:  var something = new Something();
2:  var actual = something.GetCustomAttribute<Something, StringLengthAttribute, string>(x => x.SomePublicString);

3:  actual.MinimumLength.Should().Be(1);
4:  actual.MaximumLength.Should().Be(100);
5:  actual.ErrorMessage.Should().Be("Must have between 1 and 100 characters");
```

This returns a passing test (using FluentAssertions).

However, I'd like to get the method call to GetCustomAttribute() in line 2 down to the following:

```
var actual = something.GetCustomAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>(x => x.SomePublicString);
```

Is this possible? Am I missing something? Maybe I'm on a caffeine crash. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you either have to specify *all* the type arguments, or none of them. There's no "partial" type inference.

However, one way you can sometimes get away with this is to have one generic method with a single type argument which returns an instance of a generic class, and then use type inference on that to do the rest - or vice versa. In this case, it might actually be best to separate the attribute fetching from the rest anyway:

```
something.GetPropertyAttributes(x => x.SomePublicString)
         .FirstAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>();
```

Here the first method call infers `T` and `TProperty` - and just returns an `IEnumerable<Attribute>` and `FirstAttribute` would just do the `OfType` / `FirstOrDefault` calls. (You might even decide that you don't need `FirstAttribute`, given that it's pretty simple to call `OfType` and `FirstOrDefault` yourself.)

Comment: Huzzah for the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Thanks. I originally had something like your code sample, breaking out the `PropertyInfo` reflection, custom attribute reflections, and finally, the type I wanted, but was hoping for something... leaner. :-)

Comment: @Dan, I've often heard that complaint applied to this solution and have never really understood where it's coming from.  Seems pretty lean to me (for the consumers).

Comment: It's quite lean, but I guess I was hoping that the type inference would be a bit simpler, which I believe Eric Lippert has discussed here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to infer some, but not all, of the type arguments, no.

You can either:

1. Specify all of the generic arguments.
2. Ensure that all of the generic arguments can be inferred.  (Not always possible, or the compromises needed to allow inference may not be desirable.)
3. Break the method up into multiple methods such that one method infers the generic arguments and one does not.

Comment: Thanks. My extension method infers no types though, as I have to specify all of the types used. Is this as 'clean' as I can get the method call?

Comment: @DanAtkinson Without changing the signature of the method, yes.  As I said, inference is an all or nothing thing.